# How to apply a function to all characters of a string

Tags: elm

What is the best way in Elm to apply a function to all characters of a string ?

For example, if I want to calculate the sum of all digits of a string, until I find the first "7". This is my solution. Can you propose something better?

```
sumString : Int -> String -> Int
sumString accumulator string =
    let
        firstChar =
            String.left 1 string

        rest =
            String.dropLeft 1 string
    in
    case firstChar of
        "" ->
            accumulator

        "7" ->
            accumulator

        _ ->
            sumString (accumulator + functionOnChar firstChar) rest


functionOnChar : String -> Int
functionOnChar string =
    Maybe.withDefault 0 (String.toInt string)
```

some tests:

```
suite : Test
suite =
    describe "sumString function"
        [ test "12345" <|
            \_ ->
                Expect.equal 15 (sumString 0 "12345")
        , test "123456789" <|
            \_ ->
                Expect.equal 21 (sumString 0 "123456789")
        ]
```

Comment: What is the definition of *"best"*, what would make another approach *"better"*?

Comment: short and elegant :-) My solution uses String.left and String.dropLeft, which are not specially made for this usage

Comment: You might want to try [codereview.se] instead, or the [Elm Slack server](https://elmlang.herokuapp.com/) or [Elm forums](https://discourse.elm-lang.org/). Asking for opinion is considered off-topic on Stack Overflow. See [help/on-topic].

Comment: I do not agree with you. Asking the community for the most idiomatic way of solving a problem is one of the goals of Stack-Overflow. This is not an opinion-based question.

By now, there are very few questions/answers on Elm in stack-overflow, and this really something that should change if you want Elm to have success, as much as I want.

Stack-overflow is far more easier to use to find answers (especially basic answers) than forums or slacks

Comment: @Gelineau I agree that this is a sort of question that is on-topic here. When learning a new programming language, these kinds of questions are often very helpful. I've given you an upvote :-) I do think the question could be edited for a better fit though. For example if you explained, in a couple sentences, what issues you see with your approach. Then the question would be more clear.

Comment: @Gelinea are you asking specifically about recursion or about idiomatic approaches to the problem in Elm? What motivates the question? (Either is valid but the underlying issue makes a difference to the nature of the answers.)

Comment: In fact, the question arised when we were trying to do http://kata-log.rocks/mars-rover-kata in elm. But I thought the code was a bit long for a so question, so changed the problem so that it was shorter.
We considered that the sequence of commands is given as a string.
You have to iterate on this string, but abort the sequence if the rover encounters an obstacle.

Comment: So I was interested on an idiomatic way of applying a function on every character of a string, while being able to interrupt the process

Answer (score 1):

Let's split the task into several smaller ones. Firstly, we'll want to do something for each character in the string.

1. Instead of cutting up strings, use the [higher-order functions](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/core/latest/String#higher-order-functions):

   ```
   sumUntil7 : String -> Int
   sumUntil7 string =
       String.foldl accumulateDigits 0 <| string
   ```

   Where `accumulateDigits` is the function we will define next.
2. Then we add up the digit values with an accumulator function:

   ```
   accumulateDigits : Char -> Int -> Int
   accumulateDigits char accumulator =
       accumulator + digitValue char
   ```

   Where `digitValue` is the function we'll define next.
3. For the Char to Int conversion, I have modified your approach to take a Char as argument:

   ```
   digitValue : Char -> Int
   digitValue char =
       Maybe.withDefault 0 <| String.toInt <| String.fromChar char
   ```
4. So far, we've been adding up all the digits. Now we will ignore everything starting with the first `7`, if any:

   ```
   sumUntil7 : String -> Int
   sumUntil7 string =
       String.foldl accumulateDigits 0 <| portionBefore7 string
   ```

   Where `portionBefore7` is the function we'll define next.
5. Use String.indices to find the first `7` in the string:

   ```
   portionBefore7 : String -> String
   portionBefore7 string =
       String.left
           (Maybe.withDefault (String.length string) <|
               List.head <|
                   String.indices "7" string
           )
           string
   ```

By splitting the task into smaller subtasks, and writing utility functions to accomplish them, the code has become more readable.

Full code [here](https://ellie-app.com/6xZ9cSNNfPPa1).

Comment: There is no recursion here

Comment: OP is looking for an idiomatic way of solving the problem (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57757224/how-to-recursively-apply-a-function-to-all-characters-of-a-string/57759739#comment101955896_57757224). I believe their usage of the word "recursive" is the broader sense, not the more narrow one. Explicitly recursing when higher-order functions could be used is unidiomatic and often a source of bugs.

Comment: Wether they are looking for an idiomatic way to recurse via example or just an idiomatic way of folding a string is probably better left for them to answer but the very title of the question and the first sentence of it mention reursion *and* it's tagged [tag:recursion] so if that's not what they meant it's not only off-topic but also unclear.

Comment: I think the answer is interesting, and I upvoted it. It proposes to use foldl instead of a recursion if it is possible.
However, another answer with recursion would also be appreciated (see my comment on the question : my initial problem was solving Mars Rover Kata)

Comment: @ivarni you're fixating on "recursion" and missing the point. As are down voters. `String.foldl/r` is THE CANONICAL way to "apply a function to all characters of a string".  Now the OP has clarified "I was interested on an idiomatic way of applying a function on every character of a string, while being able to interrupt the process" So we see your comments are misguided. I've upvoted O.O.Balances answer.

Comment: My comment was based on what the question was before the edit, I am sorry I was unable to predict that the question would later be changed. Apparently they still want a recursion answer as well now so it can't have been completely "misguided".